# How to prove a property of Lie derivatives

Tags: lie-algebras

I know that there are five properties for Lie derivative. But one of them I don't know how to prove. It is $ L_x[\omega(Y)]=(L_x \omega)(Y)+\omega(L_x Y)$

Note : Here $\omega$ is a covariant vector field while Y is a vector field.
Is there anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'll prove this as a collection of exercises. All of the steps should be quite doable from the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative).

**Exercise A:** prove that $\mathcal{L}_X Y = [X,Y]$

**Exercise B:** prove that $\mathcal{L}_X\omega = d(X\lrcorner\omega)+X\lrcorner d\omega$

**Exercise C:** prove that $d\omega(X,Y) = X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$

Now put these all together (remembering the Leibniz property of the Lie derivative).

Comment: What do you mean by the second exercise? I am not quite sure about the notation.@Edward Hughes

Comment: Reading [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) should help.